# Can't Seem To Make Separate Button Events

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, onclick

So I cant get these buttons to work. I've tried so many different ways. So what I've got is multiple "player" objects and they all have .div_tab buttons. And I need to be able to do things on that separate player when I click that players button. This code does nothing when I click the button.

Why? How to fix? thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i in players)
  {
    $(players[i].div_tab[0]).on('click', function() {
      console.log("Hello world!");
    });
  }
});
```

(edit)
I create the tabs with this code:

```
  this.addTab = function(name, id)
  {
    this.tabs.html(this.tabs.html() + "<div class='tab' id='"+id+"'>"+name+"</div>");
  }
  this.addTab("Select", "select");
  this.addTab("Customize", "customize");
  this.addTab("Audio Line", "audio-line");
  this.addTab("Audio Circle", "audio-circle");
  this.div_tab = this.tabs.find('div.tab');
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a loop at all. Just give the elements that need to get the callbacks a common CSS class and then you can set up the callback very simply:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".commonHandler").on('click', function() {
    console.log("Hello world!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="commonHandler">Click Me</button>
<button type="button">Click Me (but I won't do anything because I don't have the class)</button>                         <!-- <-- Not part of the group! -->
<input type="button" class="commonHandler" value="Click Me">
<span class="commonHandler">Click Me</span>
```

Comment: I need them to target their own player object, This is as you say a common handler. The console.log() will be replaced when I know it's working

Comment: @KevinBäckstäde That's what my answer can do for you. Just give each clickable element a common class and then gather them up and connect them to a common handler.

Comment: Wow took a while for me to realise how this would work... But I fixed it. Thanks! Sorry for my slow brain ;).

Answer (score -1):

For the immediate problem, I am thinking you wanted:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for (let i in players)
      {
        $(i.div_tab[0]).on('click', function() {
          console.log("Hello world!");
        });
      }
    });
```

since i is already going to be each of the instances in the list players...
More generally, looking at the rest of the page this is in might help :-).

Comment: Hmm. Interesting I logged i and it said 0 but it gave no error replacing player[i]. Is this how it works?

Comment: I guess I would be curious to know what players has in it...  But when you write that for loop, i is set to each of the values in the list, not their indices - so in your case i would be correct, players[i] ought not to work.  If the list players is a list of numbers, then you couldn't use it to select any entity on the page.  The suggestions below (like Scott's) may be a better direction to go in...

Comment: I am pretty sure that it gives us the index of each node in the array. Just curious if it did both. let a = [123, 14291, 5125915, 15, 151519515, 15, 1251591, 9];
for (let i in a)
{
  console.log(i);
}
gives: 0,1,2,3.....

Comment: `for-in` sets the variable to the indexes, not the values. You need to use `of` instead of `in` to get the values.

Comment: More generally, [why using for-in with arrays is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1)